# STD Regular Expressions in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am using the `std::regex` but there has to be something I am doing wrong. I have strings like this:

> 127.27.18.4_2.125.2.365.24.2_10

and I have to take the first field before "_" that it is an ip, the second that it is a snmp OID and the last one the polling time. These are my patterns:

```
\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+_(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.*)+_\\d+
\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+
_(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.*)+_
```

For the last one, I just serach for a digit starting from the end of the string.

Here is my code:

```
string generalCast = "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+_(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.*)+_\\d+";
string input = "";
string ip = "";

if (regex_match(input, regex(generalCast)))
{
    string ipCast = "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+";
    string oidCast = "_(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.*)+_";

    string oid = "";
    string polling = "";

    smatch matches;
    if (regex_match(input, matches, regex(ipCast)))
    {
        ip = matches[0];
        oid = "Error, bad OID: " + input;

        if (regex_match(input, matches, regex(oidCast)))
        {
            oid = regex_replace((string)matches[0], regex("_"), "");

            regex_match(input.cend(), input.cbegin(), matches, regex("\\d+"));
            if (matches.length() > 0)
            {
                polling = matches[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The case is that the program go ahead from the first if, but in the second when I ask only for the ip, it does not match.
i am used to work with regular expression in .Net and things like these work.

What am I doing wrong?

I need to use RE because I need to know when a field is coming wrong. Before I was using: stringstream and getlines.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  regular expressions in GCC before 4.9 were not supported.

Comment: Advice: use raw string literals. Backslashes are killing my eyes. Advice 2: constructing regex is expensive. Reuse them (making them staic might be a good idea)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 13. I think it is C++ v11 but not very sure.

Comment: lol "Thanks in advantage"? Now I understand how language develops. **Note:** just found [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Comment: While your regex for the ip-address will work, it will work for illegal ip-addresses as well. There are many examples of regular expressions for parsing ip-numbers if you just search a little, try to use one of those instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, by the moment I don't mind if an illegal Ip-address goes ahead. The problem is the regex does not find it in the code. I have tested the patterns in regex test tools on the internet and they work.

Comment: Does `regex_match` work on regex and input from the post? [Online compiler show that it should work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cfbe4c02152eef3). Also notice, that first capture group captures only `2.` and second only `2`

Comment: I feel like `/([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$/` is a much more straightforward approach if you are sure every line will follow the pattern you've indicated.  This will also pull out hostnames (provided they don't include underscores) in addition to IP addresses and it pulls all three values at the same time without that foolishness stripping out underscores.

Comment: I have tested them here: [link](https://ole.michelsen.dk/tools/regex.html) and they work.

Comment: Regular expressions here have produced an unreadable mess. I'd use `std::string` functions to, extract the three fields, then validate the fields separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on your code, here is a fixed snippet:

```
string generalCast = R"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+_(\d+\.)(\d+\.*)+_\d+)";
string input = "127.27.18.4_2.125.2.365.24.2_10";
string ip = "";

if (regex_match(input, regex(generalCast)))
{
    string ipCast = R"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)";
    string oidCast = R"(_(\d+\.)(\d+\.*)+_)";

    string oid = "";
    string polling = "";
    std::cout << "string object matched\n";
    smatch matches;
    if (regex_search(input, matches, regex(ipCast)))
    {
        std::cout << "ipCast matched: " << matches[0] << "\n";
        ip = matches[0];
        oid = "Error, bad OID: " + input;
        smatch matches1;
        if (regex_search(input, matches1, regex(oidCast)))
        {
            std::cout << "oidCast matched\n";
            oid = regex_replace((string)matches1[0], regex("_"), "");
            std::cout << "oid: " << oid << "\n";

            smatch matches2;
            regex_search(input, matches2, regex(R"(\d+$)"));
            if (matches2.length() > 0)
            {
                polling = matches2[0];
                std::cout << "Polling: " << polling << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/AtGhwz)

Things changed:

- You need to declare `smatch` each time in each block, you can't reuse them
- You need to use `regex_match` in the beginning only (as it requires a full string match), then, you need to use `regex_search` as it allows partial matches
- The `\d+` regex will get you the first digit sequence, not last (thus, you need `\d+$` regex).
- Using raw strings (`R"(...)"`) is more practical when defining regexes.

If you ask me, I would use something like the following (using **capturing mechanism**):

```
string generalCast = R"((\d+(?:\.\d+){3})_(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)_(\d+))";
string input = "127.27.18.4_2.125.2.365.24.2_10";
std::regex rx(generalCast);
smatch m;
if (std::regex_match(input, m, rx)) {
    std::cout << m[1].str() <<"\n";
    std::cout << m[2].str() <<"\n";
    std::cout << m[3].str() <<"\n";
}
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/GEWSTl)

Result:

```
127.27.18.4
2.125.2.365.24.2
10
```

The regex (that should match the whole string) means:

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})` - 1 or more digits followed by 3 occurrences of `.` + 1 or more digits
- `_` - a literal `_`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` - 1 or more digits followed by 1 or more occurrences of `.` + 1 or more digits
- `_` - a literal `_`
- `(\d+)` - the last 1 or more digits

Comment: Thank you so much, at the end I add too what @revolver said in his first comment, instead of declaring string, I declared the regex directly at the beginning.